# Why is pattern matching sometimes "essential" in Agda?

Tags: pattern-matching, agda, theorem-proving

Why is pattern matching sometimes "essential" in Agda?

I'm taking this out of [Programming Language Foundations in Agda](https://plfa.github.io/Connectives/).

When not pattern matching, Agda gives doesn't allow `refl` in the hole:

```
η-× : ∀ {A B : Set} (w : A × B) → ⟨ proj₁ w , proj₂ w ⟩ ≡ w
η-× x = ?
```

And it reports this goal and assumptions:

```
Goal: ⟨ proj₁ x , proj₂ x ⟩ ≡ x
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
x : A × B
```

But Agda can figure out what is going on if I tell it to case split (`ctrl-c ctrl-c x Ret)`

```
η-× : ∀ {A B : Set} (w : A × B) → ⟨ proj₁ w , proj₂ w ⟩ ≡ w
η-× ⟨ x , x₁ ⟩ = ?
```

```
Goal: ⟨ x , x₁ ⟩ ≡ ⟨ x , x₁ ⟩
```

Then Agda lets me fill in the hole with `refl`.

What's going on? How does doing the pattern match give Agda more information?

The PLFA text says:

> The pattern matching on the left-hand side is essential, since
>   replacing `w` by `⟨ x , y ⟩` allows both sides of the
>   propositional equality to simplify to the same term.

but that doesn't say *why* the pattern match helps the simplification, or when we can expect to see this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of equality constructed this way can be seen as a proof of existence of two functions: `∀ {A B : Set} (w : A × B) → ⟨ proj₁ w , proj₂ w ⟩` and `∀ {A B : Set} (w : A × B) → w`, which must be proven to produce equal output for the same inputs.

In the first case the statement requires a proof that `\ w -> ⟨ proj₁ w , proj₂ w ⟩ ≡ \ w -> w`. Agda tells you there are no definitional equalities to conclude this from. One could argue that for a single-constructor types it would be possible to work out automatically, but you can see this is not so simple in general.

In the second case, given that pattern matching proves `w ≡ ⟨ x , x₁ ⟩`, you only need a proof that `proj₁ ≡ \ ⟨ x , x₁ ⟩ -> x` and `proj₂ ≡ \ ⟨ x , x₁ ⟩ -> x₁`, which are definitional equalities.